# GHC 7.8.3 not producing binary

Tags: haskell, ghc

No binary is produced when I `ghc -O2 --make Test.hs`, but only the .o and .hi files.
Test.hs contains a `main :: IO ()` function and has module name `Test`.

Is the linker not behaving? How can I fix this?
I'm using GHC 7.8.3 on OSX, have Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn) Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0

Thank you in advance for any hints

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is the module name. GHC expects a function named `main` in a module named `Main` as a default. You can override this with the `-main-is` option. As in

```
ghc -O2 -main-is Test --make Test.hs
```

Comment: thank you, I was about to post the whole `ghc --info` but I see that is not necessary :)